# Underscore.string with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, underscore.js

I'm trying to use both [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) and [Underscore.string](https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string) with [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/).

Contents of `main.js`:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'underscore': '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.4/underscore-min',
        'underscore-string': '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.string/2.3.0/underscore.string.min',
    },
    shim: {
        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        },
        'underscore-string': {
            deps: ['underscore'],
            exports: '_s'
        },
    }
});

var modules = ['underscore-string'];

require(modules, function() {
    // --
});
```

Browser sees the `_`, but doesn't see the `_s` - it is undefined.

Ideally i want to have Underscore under `_` and Underscore.string under `_.str`, but `_` and `_s` are fine too. How can i do that?

**Versions:** RequireJS 2.1.5, Underscore 1.4.4, Underscore.string 2.3.0

**Note:** Thanks to [@jgillich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/941764/jgillich) make sure, that paths have two slashes (`//cdnjs.cloudfare.com/...`), otherwise the browser would think that URL is relative to the server, and Firebug will throw:

```
Error: Script error
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
```

Comment: I think the issue is that requirejs assumes the paths are relative to your server directory. 'underscore': '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.4/underscore-min', 'underscore-string': '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.string/2.3.0/underscore.string.min'

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to mixin Underscore plugins in RequireJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13627376/how-to-mixin-underscore-plugins-in-requirejs)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the error. For some reason RequireJS doesn't work with version of Underscore.string from [cdnjs.com](http://cdnjs.com), so i replaced it with [Github version](https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string). I guess it has something to do with the [commit 9df4736](https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string/commit/9df4736b455c2462cfd2e444cbf08c3d08bc4c07).

Currently my code looks like the following:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'underscore': '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.4/underscore-min',
        'underscore-string': '//raw.github.com/epeli/underscore.string/master/dist/underscore.string.min',
    },
    shim: {
        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        },
        'underscore-string': {
            deps: ['underscore'],
        },
    }
});

var modules = ['underscore', 'underscore-string'];

require(modules, function(_) {
    // --
});
```

Underscore.string resides in `_.str`.

**Edit:** As of 16 July 2013 the CDNJS version is [updated with the upstream](https://github.com/cdnjs/cdnjs/pull/1521).

Answer (score 2):

Battling with this for hours before i understand what i was doing wrong

This is what i did wrong

You should not rename the file underscore.string in main.js

even though in my library i did rename the file in paths i name it back to 'underscore.string'

This is how your **main.js** should look like

```
require.config({
paths: {
    underscore: 'lib/underscore', 
    'underscore.string' : 'lib/_string' ,
},
shim: { 
    underscore: {
        exports: '_', 
        deps: [ 'jquery', 'jqueryui' ]
    }, 
    'underscore.string': { 
        deps: [ 'underscore' ]
    },
} 
....
```

You could then either add it as **dependency** with in your shim like i did for my mixin file

```
shim: { 
    mixin : {
        deps: [ 'jquery',  'underscore', 'underscore.string' , 'bootstrap'  ] 
    },
```

Or just **define** it in your different pages like

```
/*global define */
define([    
    'underscore.string'
], function ( ) {
```

it just work now you can access it through _.str or _.string

This is **why** you should do it this way and not try to name it something else

on line 663 of underscore.string.js

```
  // Register as a named module with AMD.
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)
    define('underscore.string', [], function(){ return _s; });
```

Which means that it will only register it with AMD require JS if you are defining 'underscore.string'

Answer (score 1):

works for my ONLY if I use exact `"underscore.string"` module name in shim. Seems related to hardcoded name in underscore.string itself

Exempt from underscore.string source code (this branch is executed when require used):

```
 // Register as a named module with AMD.
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)
    define('underscore.string', [], function(){ return _s; });
```

So for me the only working configuration is:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'underscore': '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.4/underscore-min',
        'underscore.string': '//raw.github.com/epeli/underscore.string/master/dist/underscore.string.min',
    },
    shim: {
        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        },
        'underscore.string': {
            deps: ['underscore'],
        },
    }
});

var modules = ['underscore', 'underscore.string'];

require(modules, function(_) {
    // --
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working code using Requirejs "order" plugin, also includes Jquery, and everything loads without any conflict:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "assets",
    paths: {
        order: '//requirejs.org/docs/release/1.0.5/minified/order',
        jquery: 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min',
        underscore: '//underscorejs.org/underscore-min',
        underscorestring: '//raw.githubusercontent.com/epeli/underscore.string/master/dist/underscore.string.min',
        underscoremixed: 'js/underscore.mixed' // Create separate file 
    },
    shim: {
        underscore: { exports: '_' },
        underscorestring: { deps: ['underscore'] }
    }
});
require(['order!jquery','order!underscoremixed'], function($,_) {
    // test
    console.log( _.capitalize('capitalized text') );
});
```

Inside **js/underscore.mixed.js** put the following...

```
define(['underscore','underscorestring'], function() {
    _.mixin(_.str.exports());
    return _;
});
```

Cheers! :)